# Session sharing is not enabled | Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am currently trying to show Routes in my app, but I get [UserSession] maps short session requested but session sharing is not enabled in the console.
I separated the MapView and calculation of the route in different structs / classes, so that might be the reason. I never heard of the UserSession

```
[UserSession] maps short session requested but session sharing is not enabled
```

I have seen people online say this is a bug in iOS 15 / Xcode but I have not found any solution or explanation for what this error means.

Comment: Please show us code

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this error appears every time I use getDirections but does not impede the return of results. I was stumped by it, too, until I listed the steps resulting from calling getDirections and saw that they were complete and correct.

The error (warning) itself appears to be internal to Apple's MKDirections framework and not a result of our code.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I am also receiving the same error with `Mac OSX BigSur` and `XCode 13.2`, so I performed a test with a VM running `Mac OSX Catalina`:

https://github.com/myspaghetti/macos-virtualbox

Then I downloaded, installed and ran XCode 12.4,

https://xcodereleases.com/

When I built a `MapKit` / `CoreLocation` application (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtYEGsi2HB4), it ran fine on `OSX Catalina` but I got the same error as above on `BigSur`. Hopefully, Apple will fix this issue soon with an update.

**UPDATE:**

It appears that Apple is deprecating their Apple Maps with their `Main.storyboard` designer because I have a colleague who used Apple Maps without a problem but that was using `SwiftUI` which has no UI designer--instead everything is specified in code for the UI.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this weird issue.

Comment: I have a colleague who built his application entirely using `SwiftUI` and he had no problems with maps so maybe it has something to do with the `Main.storyboard` designer?

Comment: Was thinking that as well,  I am also using Main.storyboard