# (UserSession) maps short session requested but session sharing is not enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, mapkit

I am trying to use iOS MapKit's [`MKDirections.Request`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections/request).
My requests are failing with the following error:

```
[UserSession] maps short session requested but session sharing is not enabled
```

I have the following toy code:

```
  MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];

  double latitude = 35.0;
  double longitude = 1.0;
  MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) addressDictionary:nil];

  request.source = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];;
  request.destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];;
  request.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;
  MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

  [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          ... some code here
        } else {
          ... this is where I see the error
        }
  }];
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This question is a duplicate and was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75665469/14034770).